# Laravel nested relationship

Tags: laravel, relationship

User can have many devices and each device can have many interfaces.

I want to get user with his devices and each device's interfaces.

**User model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
        'profile_image', 'retrieve_email', 'retrieve_sms'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function devices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Device');
    }

}
```

**Device Model**

```
class Device extends Model
{
    public function interfaces()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ModelInterface');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}
```

**ModelInterface Model**

```
class ModelInterface extends Model
{
    public function device()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Device');
    }

    public function alerts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Alerts');
    }
}
```

How can i get the user's interfaces?

```
Auth::user()->devices returns all the devices and works.
```

How could i possibly say

```
Auther::user()->devices->interfaces
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to look at the [HasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship.

> The "has-many-through" relationship provides a convenient shortcut for accessing distant relations via an intermediate relation. For example, a Country model might have many Post models through an intermediate User model. In this example, you could easily gather all blog posts for a given country.

Something along these lines on your User model:

```
return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Interface', 'App\Device');
```

as your User has many Interfaces *through* their Devices.

Comment: So i have to change the `App\Interface` to belong to `App\Device` AND `App\User`? Right now it only belongs to `App\Device`

Comment: @AntoniosTsimourtos No. Interfaces belong to devices. Devices belong to users. Thus, interfaces belong to users **through** their devices. The `hasManyThrough` relationship understands this sort of nested relationship and thus can be used to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! This is what i actually want to achieve. So do I have to put the single code line on my User model? Should anything be changed on the migrations? Could you please edit your answer and write the whole Model(s) changes?

Comment: @AntoniosTsimourtos Please read the link to the documentation I included. It includes an example database structure and all the details necessary to implement.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through the devices and get interfaces for each device.

```
foreach(Auth::user()->devices as $device)
{
   foreach($device->interfaces as $interface)
   {
       // do whatever you want
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes but i don't want to get the actual objects just the count of all the `$interfaces` so i want to avoid the loop iteration

Comment: Then you have to use `hasManyThrough` and then use `count()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
$id = Auth::user()->id;

$userwithDetails = User::with('devices', 'devices.interfaces')->where('id', $id)->first();
```

This will give you user with a collection of all devices of that user, each device will have another collection of interfaces belonging to  that device.